# Object radiance value buffer

Tags: cycles-render-engine

The "wiki" states that an objects radiance value is written out into the render float buffer.  Where in the source code is this buffer and how do I access it (variable name?)

Comment: Hello, if you don't find suitable answers here you can try https://devtalk.blender.org/

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. Found it.  It's in the `path_radiance_accum function`